# Dangerous to create partitions in unallocated space on the same disk as the running Linux system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, gpt, partition-table

For context, I have a Fedora KDE installation whose partitions take up half my SSD. The other half I left unallocated when I installed Linux.

Although I'm aware that it's dangerous to attempt to extend any of the existing Fedora partitions without booting from a `gparted` USB environment or similar, I had previously assumed it was safe to create new partitions in the unallocated space from within my Fedora environment (whether the GUI partition manager or `fdisk`, etc).

But I just read in How Linux Works (Brian Ward) that when modifying partition tables,

> Ensure that no partitions on your target disk are currently in use. This is a concern because most Linux distributions automatically mount any detected filesystems.

However, it's unclear to me from the context whether he is talking about MBR or GPT or both.

So my question is, is it dangerous to make any changes whatsoever to a GPT partition table on the same disk as the partitions of the currently-running Linux environment, even if you aren't extending/shrinking the existing partitions?

Comment: Creating a new partition is different from creating a new file system, so that warning is wrong, even applying the caution it seems based on, there's no problem in creating partitions. (But some tools might do both by default).

Comment: IIRC the kernel doesn't let you reload the partition table (to find and use the new partitions) if any partition on the same drive is mounted. So while editing the partition table online is fine, it's not immediately useful, and you'll need to at least reboot. Which incidentally would also be the point where you'd find out if you trashed the original partitions when modifying the partition table, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating, deleting, and modifying partitions in an **unallocated** space of the same disk containing running Linux partitions is not an issue.  The `fdisk` command, and other partitioning tools, do that all the time.

> because most Linux distributions automatically mount any detected filesystems.

Even assuming that this is true (filesystems need to have an entry in `/etc/fstab` for the system to mount them), this is not an issue, because when you're modifying these partitions there is no filesystem on it. First you create the partition, then you create a filesystem (the non-techie term for this is *formatting*) on it.

Comment: It works with gpt but back with MBR(msdos), and if any mounted Linux partition was logical, you could not unmount the extended partition. So then could not edit anything inside the extended partition.